# Tensorflow example works fine on colab, but gives nan while running on jupyter lab

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory, jupyter-lab

After working with the tensorflow's example tutorial on colab: Basic regression: Predict fuel efficiency, which can be found here: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/regression.
I've been trying to run this example on jupyter notebook via anaconda in order to be able to run it offline too.
The code that one can find on the link works fine on google colab, but when I try to run it on jupyter notebook I get a vector of nan's.

1. A run on google colab yields:
   [Running the example on google colab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wvafS.png)
2. A run on jupyter yields:
   [Running the example on jupyter lab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BvRkU.png)

**The code for building the sequential model: [where the problem might come from]**

```
horsepower_model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    horsepower_normalizer,
    layers.Dense(units=1)
])

horsepower_model.summary()
```

**The rest of the code can be found in this link that I have attached above:**
https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/regression

**What the model has to do:**
This model takes 2 arrays from a dataset: MPG and Horsepower, and is about to use single-variable linear regression in order to predict MPG from Horsepower.
Therefore, the model is introduce a Dense layer with shape of 1 as one can see from here:

```
layers.Dense(units=1)
```

The output of the model should be the values of the MPG, based on the horsepower values.
Then we will be able to compare it with the values of the real MPG that we've got from the dataset.

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT: I upload my notebook:**
https://www.udrop.com/Jk3/Horsepower.ipynb

Comment: In the first image the  `normalization_1` layer has an output shape of `(None, 1)` whereas in the second image it is `(None, 314)`. Please include the code for the input shape of both examples.

Comment: The code that I've used is the code that you can find in this link below:
https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/regression
I've saved this code and tried to run it on my jupyter lab via anaconda.
It is the same code in both colab and jupyter.
I don't see why I got different output shape for the normalization_1 layer.
Thank you for trying to help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you are using different models in them.
In **Colab** you have used model having only **5** parameters
whereas in **Notebook** you are using a dense model having **944** parameters.

**Try running the model with less parameter on notebook first**
or
Try running the same model on both.(Maybe the complex model was not trained completely.)

**EDIT 1:**
I have created a jupyter notebook and tried the code.
In my system it is working fine, try running this jupyter notebook in your system. [Jupyter Notebook](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dDiJZ7LAsR5x3bz1Y-7EetTwWX2mXEjG/view?usp=sharing)
. If it works then maybe there is some syntax error in your code.

**EDIT 2:**
Update tensorflow:

```
pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade tensorflow
```

use this or any other command that works on your version.

Comment: This is exactly what I've thought.
But the way I've made the model is the same in both colab and jupyter.
This is the reason why I don't understand why it should work in colab but not in jupyter.
There is no reason why the number of parameters should have come out not exactly the same in both colab and jupyter notebook.

Comment: can you share the model details, because its a bit unclear here that what the model is exactly doing

Comment: sure, just edited.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: I am sharing my notebook in the answer. I am editing the answer check it and let me know.

Comment: Are you sure that you ran it on jupyter lab via anaconda?
for some reason I still get the same problem:
https://ibb.co/JB8drvD
thank you

Comment: Can you share you notebook? with the outputs

Comment: sure, I will be able to upload it in 2 days.
I also wanted to ask, it might be a problem of missing packages?
I thought that tensorflow is installing automatically cudnn and cuda toolkit,
while for gpu support I have to install the relevant driver by myself, am I right?
again, thank you very much for your help

Comment: yes you are right. This may be the reason. Let me know when you upload it.
also, can you give my answer a tick, it helps in building repo.

Comment: Hi, I uploaded my notebook.  
Is my tick to your answer is okay? didn't notice it at first - sorry.

Comment: actually you ticked my comment not the answer. no problem in that though, I saw your notebook, try updating your tensorflow. and try running it again.

Comment: Thank you very much it worked. So the problem was the version of my tensorflow-gpu? 2.1 is not good anymore?

Comment: there are some changes in the way of sequential models parameter intake, also keras got separated.

Answer (score 0):

Putting an extra set of brackets around each horsepower value fixes the issue for me:

```
horsepower = np.array([[h] for h in train_features['Horsepower']])
```